# cllocation and mkreversegeocoder

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager, cllocation, mkreversegeocoder

i'm try to retreiving city name with cllocation and mkreversegeocoder.
in my viewdidload method i istance cllocationmanager:

```
self.locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locManager.delegate = self;
locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and after:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation 
*)newLocation
fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
//some code to retrieve my information

MKReverseGeocoder *geoCoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc]     
initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate ];
geoCoder.delegate = self;
[geoCoder start];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark  
*)placemark
{
MKPlacemark *myPlacemark = placemark;
citta.text = [placemark locality];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
citta.text =@ "Unknow";
```

Application works only the first time i get my value. on the second time app crash. 
I think is because geocoder is started and i think i must have one and only one istance running. (but i'm really not shure of this...). in which way i can controll geocoder is running?

I've see that i can istance mkreversegeocoder in my viewdidload using cllocationcoordinate2d but ... in which way i can retreive newlocation.coordinate?

I've partially resolve declaring geocoder as class variable and checking

```
if (self.geocoder != nil) {
   [geocoder release];
}
```

but.... if in my

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark  
*)placemark
```

or in my

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailedWithError:(@NSError 
*)error
```

i release or cancel my object?
I'm feeling so stupid :D

Comment: `[nil release];` works (does nothing) so there is no need to check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't create the reverse geocoder as a local variable.

Look at the MKReverseGeocoder example in the [CurrentAddress](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app provided by Apple.  See MapViewController.h and MapViewController.m.

Follow the same pattern in your code.

Comment: shure at the end i've do in this way, now i've modify with autorelease  an no checking if geocoder is running anyway